# python requests unexpectedly decode application/x-gzip content

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm attempting to retrieve https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Txt/Synop/Archive/synop.201803.csv.gz using python requests.

However, when accessing response's content I get the csv data, not the gzipped-csv data like I would have expected. It's not clear to me why.

```
>>> url
'https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Txt/Synop/Archive/synop.201803.csv.gz'
>>> resp = requests.get(url)
>>> resp.headers
{'Date': 'Thu, 19 Apr 2018 10:48:11 GMT', 'Server': 'MFWS', 
 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 31 Mar 2018 21:10:09 GMT', 
 'ETag': '"3066bd-a2dce-568bbc81bee40"', 
 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 
 'Content-Length': '667086', 
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-gzip', 
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment', 
 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=300',
 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'}
>>> resp.content[:100]
b'numer_sta;date;pmer;tend;cod_tend;dd;ff;t;td;u;vv;ww;w1;w2;n;nbas;hbas;cl;cm;ch;pres;niv_bar;geop;te'
>>> requests.__version__
'2.18.4'
```

If I access the same URL with e.g. curl I get the gzipped content as expected:

```
$ curl https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/donnees_libres/Txt/Synop/Archive/synop.201803.csv.gz  -s > data
$ file data
data: gzip compressed data, was "synop.201803.csv", last modified: Sat Mar 31 21:10:08 2018, from Unix
```

Is this a requests feature I don't get? A server misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature indeed, see [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/#encoded-data).

> Encoded Data?
>
> Requests automatically decompresses gzip-encoded responses, and does its best to decode response content to unicode when possible.
>
> You can get direct access to the raw response (and even the socket), if needed as well.

Comment: thx. I still feel bad about that. In the response has "Content-type" = 'application/gzip', and also I don't attempt to access `response.text`, so in this case this behaviour is at best clumsy...